# if loop for replacing values

Tags: python, if-statement, replace

I have following total-20-line data

```
1  2  5  4  1
2  2  2  3  3
3  3  4  1  2
4  3  5  1  2
5  4  3  8  4
....
```

I hope to store each columns, and want to replace some values on specific if-loop conditions, and write the line number, how many replaced values occurs in some columns. I wrote a code like

```
n_lines = 20
A = [None] * n_lines
B = [None] * n_lines
C = [None] * n_lines
D = [None] * n_lines
E = [None] * n_lines
with open ('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
   for i in range(n_lines):      ### Read everything to data_lines
       data_lines[i] = file.readline()
   for j in range(n_lines):      ### Read and store column by column
       data = data_lines[j].split()
       A[j] = int(data[0])
       B[j] = int(data[1])
       C[j] = int(data[2])
       D[j] = int(data[3])
       E[j] = int(data[4])
   for k in range(n_lines):      ### Analyze table 
       if B[k] == 2:             ### Check if 2nd column's value is 2
          c1 = C[k]              ### If it is, read 3rd column and 4th column, store them as c1 and d1. 
          d1 = D[k]
          if ((B[c1] == 4) and (B[d1] == 4)):     ### Check if 2nd column's c1-th and d1-th values are 4
             B[k] = 9            ### If those conditions are met, replace B[k] value from 2 to 9      
          elif ((D[c1] + E[d1] >= 10)):
             B[k] = 10           #### If this condition is met, replace B[k] value from 2 to 10   
   num_9 = [B[k]].count(9)       ### Count the occurrence number of replaced value 9
   num_10 = [B[k]].count(10)     ### Count the occurrence number of replaced value 10
   out = '%5d'%k + '%5d'%num_9 + '%5d'%num_10      ### Print out
   outfile.write(out)
   outfile.write('\n')
outfile.close()
```

But I'm facing

```
if ((B[c1] == 4) and (B[d1] == 4)):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I can't understand why 'out of range' error occurs. Same error happens in 'elif ((D[c1] + E[d1] >= 10)):' line, too. All columns (A~E) are in right size. My way of if-loop expressions are wrong? Or my way of replacing is wrong? (My other data in same format is in 15000 lines with 100 data-blcoks, so I hope to keep using for-loop for indexing. )

Thank you

Comment: You have a matrix of numbers, consider storing them in a data structure like list-of-lists or `numpy.ndarray`.

Comment: @BrianCain Thanks, but I failed to index and access to the each elements in list of list and array form (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26208434/multidimension-array-indexing-and-column-accessing), so I decided to use this form. At least I feel more comfortable with indexing, accessing, and split/readlines command in here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only 20 elements in B[] according to your code. This error means you want to visit an element whose index is out of range. You can confirm with this:

```
...
for k in range(n_lines):      ### Analyze table 
       if B[k] == 2:             ### Check if 2nd column's value is 2
          c1 = C[k]              ### If it is, read 3rd column and 4th column, store them as c1 and d1. 
          d1 = D[k]
          print 'B[] has only 20 elements, now I try to visit %dth and %dth element.' % (c1, d1)
          if ((B[c1] == 4) and (B[d1] == 4)):     ### Check if 2nd column's c1-th and d1-th values are 4
             B[k] = 9            ### If those conditions are met, replace B[k] value from 2 to 9      
          elif ((D[c1] + E[d1] >= 10)):
             B[k] = 10           #### If this condition is met, replace B[k] value from 2 to 10   
...
```

Then you will know where you went wrong. Hope it helps. :)

EDIT:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

n_lines = 20
A = []
B = []
C = []
D = []
E = []
with open ('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in file.readlines():
        data = line.split()

        A.append(int(data[0]))
        B.append(int(data[1]))
        C.append(int(data[2]))
        D.append(int(data[3]))
        E.append(int(data[4]))
    for k in xrange(n_lines):      ### Analyze table 
        if B[k] == 2:             ### Check if 2nd column's value is 2
            c1 = C[k]              ### If it is, read 3rd column and 4th column, store them as c1 and d1. 
            d1 = D[k]
            if ((B[c1] == 4) and (B[d1] == 4)):     ### Check if 2nd column's c1-th and d1-th values are 4
                B[k] = 9            ### If those conditions are met, replace B[k] value from 2 to 9      
            elif ((D[c1] + E[d1] >= 10)):
                B[k] = 10           #### If this condition is met, replace B[k] value from 2 to 10   
    num_9 = B.count(9)       ### Count the occurrence number of replaced value 9
    num_10 = B.count(10)     ### Count the occurrence number of replaced value 10
    out = ''.join(['%5d'%k, '%5d'%num_9, '%5d'%num_10])
    outfile.write(out)
    outfile.write('\n')
```

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem and solved. No more errors. But still, the result is far away from my expectation. Do you think my way of replacing is good here?

Comment: @exsonic01 Your code is readable but not pythonic. It's good for work but not good enough. So, if my answer helps, don't forget to accept it as an answer. :)

Comment: What is that way of pythonic for my code? I'd tried but keep failed to index and access each elements of multi-dimension array or lists.(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26208434/multidimension-array-indexing-and-column-accessing) 

And it seems that the count() is not working for my columns. Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: @exsonic01 I just give you an example. If there is something wrong in it, I'm sure you can fix it by yourself. :)